# How can I import socket.io library in chrome extension in manifest version3?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, socket.io, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, manifest.json

I am currently working on a project to make a chrome extension.

Using the socket.io library in background.js, we are trying to make a feature that allows clients to communicate with each other through extensions.

However, I couldn't find a way to import the socket.io library in manifest version 3.
Is there any way to make this possible in manifest version 3? Or is there any other way to use socket.io in chrome extension?

I tried require() and import method to use socket.io in background.js but it failed.
I put socketio "dependencies" in manifest.json file but I'm not sure it's working.
Also, I copy and pasted socket.io.js code inside the background.js to mock importing library but it also failed.

Comment: It won't work until socketio publishes a ManifestV3-compatible version. The workaround is to do it inside an [offscreen](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/offscreen) document, currently it can be tested in Chrome Canary.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Too bad it won't work. 
But I'm not sure what offscreen document is. Do you mean popup.html? or is it only in the Chrome Canary?

Comment: @SungtaeKim - You should ask this on https://github.com/socketio/socket.io in the Issues section. And the Socket.IO website really shouldn't link to Stack Overflow.

Comment: See the link in my first comment.